# jQuery mmenu - On opening a submenu how to close all others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

we are using mmenu (v4.7.5), that is really great by the way, together with jQuery v1.11.1.

I initialise it with these options / configuration:

```
IwAG.$('nav#menu').mmenu({
    "slidingSubmenus": false
}, {
    clone: true
});
```

When opening a submenu, I want that all other open submenues close automatically.

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution ;)

```
$('nav#menu ul.first_level').on("open.mm", function (e) {
    var parent = IwAG.$(e.target).closest('li');
    var siblings = parent.siblings('li.mm-opened');
    if (siblings) {
        siblings.find('.mm-opened').removeClass('mm-opened');
        siblings.removeClass('mm-opened');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $('.mm-navbar__btn').click(function(){
                
        var myMenu = $(this).closest('.mm-listitem--vertical');
            $('.mm-listitem--vertical').not(myMenu).removeClass('mm-listitem--opened');
            })

        $('.mm-wrapper__blocker').click(function(){  
            var myMenu = $(this).closest('.mm-listitem--vertical');
            $('.mm-listitem--vertical').not(myMenu).removeClass('mm-listitem--opened');
            })          
        })
</script>
```

.mm-navbar__btn      close menu button

.mm-wrapper__blocker click on the darkened background of the site

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).